# Twig Without Symfony - Including Templates with Different Logic Within Template

Tags: php, twig

I can find plenty of information about using Twig with Symfony, but not much about using Twig WITHOUT Symfony.

**What I want to Do**

What I'm looking to do is include a template within a template. I have a base.twig template that I want to include a header template in. Easy enough, right?

```
{% include "header.twig" %}
```

**The Problem**

I'm now running into an issue because the header template has a lot of logic in it. I don't want to have to pass values to my header template from the controller of each page. That's just messy and would eliminate many of the benefits of using Twig.

**The Question**

Is there a way to include a separate controller for the header from within the base.twig template? Any recommendations for making this a cleaner setup (without switching to Symfony--that's not an option for me at this point)?

Answer (score 0):

What I would try to do:

1. Remove as much logic as possible form a template.

   - Business logick does not belong in template.
2. Use [set](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html) to preset defaults for variables.
3. Create helper function/view helper to build header.